# What could be preventing the NodeMouseClick event from firing?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, treenode

I'm working with a windows form app which I have treeview to show the list of folders , and I have attached `NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)` event.
and on click of node I call server method to populate the treeview.
Here I could see that NodeMouseClick for one of my tree node is not at all getting triggered.
however for rest of the nodes its working fine with no issues. can anyone tell me what is the exact reason that its not getting triggered.
and I dont want to use After_Select event.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add("root");

        for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
        {
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(i.ToString());
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes[i].Nodes.Add("child" + i.ToString());
        }

        treeView1.Nodes[0].Expand();
    }
```

use treeview of size = 280,369

Comment: I'd love to help, but your problem is completely unreproducible without posting your code. The `NodeMouseClick` event works *every time* for me, so you have to be doing something wrong. Post your code and we'll work out what it is.

Comment: So...which node is it that isn't getting selected? I set up a test project *exactly* like you described, and hooked up a `NodeMouseClick` event handler that displays `e.Node.Text` in a label off to the side. It works properly for every one that I click, even if I click the +/- box to the side of the node, rather than the node's text itself. I can't seem to make it *not* work. Is there a particular node whose click event fails every time? An approximate location?

Comment: yes  the "last node" in the treeview - click on the plus sign of last node by keeping the breakpoint on NodeMouseClick . you can see that it never gets hit.  http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/266215/treeview-nodemouseclick-event-sometimes-is-not-fired

Comment: @user595581: Hmm, that bug report is terrible. I'm not even sure if I know what it means. But I'll check out that last node thing. I have a workaround in mind if it turns out to be a bug, but it's a little big ugly... You'll have to P/Invoke to detect mouse clicks and raise the event yourself. Just how important is it to you to get this right?

Comment: @Cody Gray - could you pls share the code p/invoke.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned before in the comments, the workaround is to drop down to the level of the Windows API, intercept mouse messages, and raise the node click event yourself. The code is ugly, but functional.

Add the following code to a new class in your project (I called it `CustomTreeView`):

```
class CustomTreeView : System.Windows.Forms.TreeView
{
    public event EventHandler<TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs> CustomNodeClick;

    private const int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201;

    protected override void WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)  // left mouse button down
        {
            // get the current position of the mouse pointer
            Point mousePos = Control.MousePosition;

            // get the node the user clicked on
            TreeNode testNode = GetNodeAt(PointToClient(mousePos));

            // see if the clicked area contained an actual node
            if (testNode != null)
            {
                // A node was clicked, so raise our custom event
                var e = new TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs(testNode,
                                 MouseButtons.Left, 1, mousePos.X, mousePos.Y);
                if (CustomNodeClick != null)
                    CustomNodeClick(this, e);
            }
        }

        // call through to let the base class process the message
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

Then change all references to the `System.Windows.Forms.TreeView` control in your code to the new `CustomTreeView` class that you just created. This is a *subclass* of the existing `TreeView` control that you want to use instead. In case you're not familiar with subclassing, this is the way we modify the existing functionality, or bolt on new functionality to, an existing control. In this case, we've subclassed the original `TreeView` control to add the `CustomNodeClick` event that we'll be raising ourselves whenever we detect that a node has been clicked by the user.

Finally, change the event handler method in your form class to listen for the `CustomNodeClick` event that we're raising, rather than the buggered `NodeMouseClick` event you were trying to use before.

Compile and run. Everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `AfterSelect` Event it must be triggered after any node selection  .